# kendo ui datasource read method makes two requests

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a grid with a datasource read method

```
 this.editorGridConfig = {
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: options => {
                    this.getSummaryData().then(res => {
                            options.success(res.data);
                    });
                }
            }

getSummaryData() {
    console.log('get summary data');
    let url = 'myEndPoint';
    return ajaxRequest(url);
}
```

The getSummaryData is been called successfully and returns an array of objects.
The problem is when the options.success(res.data) is called kendo makes a new request on the this.getSummaryData is called twice.

Comment: It might be possible that by mistake you have added/referenced any js files twice in your page.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using a **kendo route** then this is the issue.

**router.navigate('/page/' + e.index);** 
fires **read()** inside *pagination onChange() and dataSource.query()*

**Solution is** :

```
var url = window.location.href;
var pagelessUrl = url.indexOf("/page/") === -1 ? url.length - 1 : url.indexOf("/page/");
window.history.pushState('page'+e.index, document.title, url.substring(0,pagelessUrl)+"/page/" + e.index);
```